# How to set one icon in left and text in center in header in react native

Tags: react-native

Am trying to set my icon in left and text in center (like Image which I have give)  in header  by using flex but they both are going in center how to solve it.

```js
    import React, { Component } from 'react'
    import {
      AppRegistry,
      StyleSheet,
      Text,
      View,
    } from 'react-native'

    export default class App extends Component {
      render() {
        return (
          <View style={styles.container}>
            <View style={styles.header}>
            <Text style={styles.cross}>X</Text>
            <Text style={styles.headerText}>Invester Profile</Text>
            </View>
          </View>
        )
      }
    }

    const styles = StyleSheet.create({
      container: {
        flex: 1,
      },
      welcome: {
        fontSize: 20,
        textAlign: 'center',
        margin: 10,
      },

      header: {
        backgroundColor:'#212121',
        height: 159.9,
        flexDirection: 'row',
      },
      headerText: {
        color: 'white',
        marginTop: 20,
        textAlign: 'center',

      },
      cross: {
        color: 'white',
        marginTop: 20,
      }
    })
```

Answer (score 0):

Just add flex: 1 to headerText. Like this:

```
  headerText: {
    color: 'white',
    marginTop: 20,
    textAlign: 'center',
    flex: 1
  }
```